# Numexpr detecting number of threads less than number of cores

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-computing, python-multithreading, numexpr

I am using numexpr for simple array addition on a remote cluster. My computer has 8 cores and the remote cluster has 28 cores. Numexpr documentation says that "During initialization time Numexpr sets this number to the number of detected cores in the system" But the cluster gives this output.
detect_number_of_cores() = 28
detect_number_of_threads()=8

ALthough when I try to set the number of threads manually to something else(set_num_threads=20) , array operation seems to run faster. But detect_number_of_threads() still gives 8 as output.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score -1):

I´m not sure, how numexpr actually works internally, when detect_number_of_threads is called, but maybe it reads out the number of threads that is available to openmp and not the number of threads that were locally set.

Comment: If you're not sure, why are you postin an answer?